# What is the correct implementation of a "composite" variable type?

Tags: c#, variables, c#-4.0

I have a program that have to manage objects with a composite key.
this key, to be simple is a couple of strings.

I have the following code :

```
public struct MyKey
{
    public string Part1 { get; set;} // always set
    public string Part2 { get; set;} // can be null
    public MyKey(string part1, string part2) : this()
    {
        this.Part1 = part1;
        this.Part2 = part2;
    }
}
```

this is ok for storing my values.

Now I want to be able to :

- use the equals operator (part1 and part2 are equals)
- use the key in a Dictionnary, especially for using Contains method

I've guessing a number of things (override equals operator, overriding GetHashCode and Equals methods, implementing IComparable, etc.), but I'm not sure what are the necessary steps to reach my goals and what will cause an overhead.

thx in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use .NET 4.0 `Tuple`, it has a correct `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` based on the component values.  I've used Tuple before or if they are string keys you can always concat with a separator, but if you truly want to keep that class as your key you do want a proper Equals() and GetHashCode(), so in that case have YourType implement `IEqualityComparer<YourType>`.

p.s.  Here's a good example of overriding the GetHashCode() if you want to do that manually instead of a Tuple...

[What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode)

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in order to use your object as a key in a dictionary. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overriden-in-c) provides an excellent explanation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would stay away from `struct` because of **boxing** and various coding pitfalls it can fall us into.

I would override both `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. `GetHashCode` since it is used in dictionaries and `Equals` since it is used by various ORMs and can be handy in implementing business logic.

Comment: FYI, Equals is also used in dictionaries.